# Why site.webmanifest is not being served by Azure AppService

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

Chrome automatically tries to download site.manifest on my website.

However, the website is returning a 404 error.

Yet the file does exist in wwwroot, and so should be downloadable.

Is there some setting required in order to allow this file to be downloaded by the browser?

This is an asp.netcore 2.1 project running on Azure.